# Class template, which is independent of the permutations of its arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, class-template

Consider a class template and auxiliary enum classes defined as follows:

```
enum class Color {Red, Green, Blue}
enum class ShowAxes {False, True}
enum class ShowLabels {False, True}

template< Color, ShowAxes, ShowLabels >
class A
{......};
```

The question is, how to redefine the class A, which would be independent on the permutations of its arguments. I use Dev C++, which supports C++11.

**[EDIT]**

For example, the new version of A should support

```
A< Color::Red, ShowAxes::True, ShowLabels::True >
A< Color::Red, ShowLabels::True, ShowAxes::True >
A< ShowAxes::True, Color::Red, ShowLabels::True >
A< ShowLabels::True, Color::Red, ShowAxes::True >
A< ShowLabels::True, Color::Red, ShowAxes::True >
A< ShowAxes::True, Color::Red, ShowLabels::True >
```

versions, and all of them are identical, i.e. they generate the same class.

Comment: c++ class template specialization?

Comment: @BryanChen you can't change the types of parameters with a specialization

Comment: I don't want to change the types of parameters. The specialization is a good idea, but I have 3! = 6 permutations. Moreover, I am going to add more parameters.

Comment: Not possible with non-type parameters of different types. You can take type parameters and wrap the value in a type like `std::integral_constant`, but it gets verbose rather quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible with your current interface using non-type parameters.

You can take type parameters instead and wrap the values in a `std::integral_constant`:

```
template<class X, class Y, class Z>
class A { /* stuff */ };

// use as:
A<std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Red>,
  std::integral_constant<ShowAxes, ShowAxes::True>,
  std::integral_constant<ShowLabels, ShowLabels::True>> a;
```

This is rather verbose, so you could consider writing a macro:

```
#define AS_IC(Value) std::integral_constant<decltype(Value), Value>
```

and rewrite as

```
A<AS_IC(Color::Red), AS_IC(ShowAxes::True), AS_IC(ShowLabels::True)> a;
```

Extracting the value of the desired type from the list of `integral_constant`s is straightforward:

```
template<class Result, class...>
struct extract;

template<class Result, Result Value, class... Tail>
struct extract<Result, std::integral_constant<Result, Value>, Tail...> : std::integral_constant<Result, Value> {};

template<class Result, class Head, class... Tail>
struct extract<Result, Head, Tail...> : extract<Result, Tail...> {};
```

Then you can do

```
// inside the definition of A
static constexpr Color col = extract<Color, X, Y, Z>::value;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ae003ea2284eefa).

This do not, however, generate the same class, but you can make a class template `A_impl` that behaves like your `A` with non-type parameters, and that contains the actual implementation, and then make `A` an alias template:

```
template< Color, ShowAxes, ShowLabels >
class A_impl
{/* stuff */};

template<class X, class Y, class Z>
using A = A_impl<extract<Color, X, Y, Z>::value,
                 extract<ShowAxes, X, Y, Z>::value,
                 extract<ShowLabels, X, Y, Z>::value>;
```

Now given

```
A<AS_IC(Color::Red), AS_IC(ShowAxes::True), AS_IC(ShowLabels::True)> a;
A<AS_IC(Color::Red), AS_IC(ShowLabels::True), AS_IC(ShowAxes::True)> b;
```

`a` and `b` have the same type. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d29dab0858bd75f7).

In the alternative, you can also use `decltype` and overloading function templates, but that requires adding a function template declaration for every possible order of types:

```
template< Color c, ShowAxes a, ShowLabels l>
A<c,a,l> A_of();

template< ShowAxes a, ShowLabels l, Color c>
A<c,a,l> A_of();

// etc.

decltype(A_of<Color::Red, ShowAxes::True, ShowLabels::True>()) a1;
decltype(A_of<ShowAxes::True, ShowLabels::True, Color::Red>()) a2;
```

Comment: The idea of `std::integral_constant` and `extract` looks nice. I will think about optimization of the code.

Comment: I have a small (maybe trivial) question. Is it possible to replace a macro AS_IC by a non-directive staff, say a class template or template function ?

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan No macro-free way that I'm aware of without adding lots of boilerplate when you declare an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). Then you can simplify your code this way:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class X
{
public:
    X() {
        static_assert(
            std::is_same<A, Color>::value ||
            std::is_same<B, Color>::value ||
            std::is_same<C, Color>::value,
            "nope");
        // other assertions here!
        // also, make sure your types are different ;)
    }
    X(A a, B b, C c) : X() {
        // your code here
    }
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
X<A, B, C> make(A a, B b, C c) {
    // possible verifications here
    return X<A, B, C>(a, b, c);
}

int main() {
    auto a = make(Color::Red, ShowAxes::true, ShowLabels::True);
    return 0;
}
```

You can verify all of your types A, B & C.

I'm sorry, but I don't see any other solution. :/

Comment: I added some text in the question for the detailed explanation of my aim.

Comment: Thank you, but for example `make(Color::Red, ShowAxes::True, ShowLabels::True)` and `make(ShowAxes::True, Color::Red, ShowLabels::True)` give different results. They should generate the same class.

Comment: Can inheritance resolve the problem? If the X class inherits from a Base class, they can be of the same type thanks to polymorphism.